# Python 3.6.1 does not find package and module [import]

Tags: python, import, package, python-import

I am starting a Python project, and I have structured my code in packages and sub-packages in the following way:

```
FCM
|-- definitions
|   |-- Classifiers
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- triggers
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- probability.py
|-- examples
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- compute
|   `-- study
`-- source
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- FastComposedModels_pb2.py
    |-- genetic_algorithm
    `-- trigger_evaluator.py
```

Module imports between sub-packages work, however when I try to import the triggers subpackage from inside ./examples or ./source:

```
import definitions.triggers
```

I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'definitions.triggers'
```

Here's the sys.path variable value:

```
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages
/home/projects/FCM
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python36.zip
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytz-2017.2-py3.6.egg
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/packaging-16.8-py3.6.egg
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/appdirs-1.4.3-py3.6.egg
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cycler-0.10.0-py3.6.egg
/apps/PYTHON/3.6.1/INTEL/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-py3.6.e
```

I am using Python 3.6.1 in Linux, however, this does not happen to me in any other platform and python version. I do not understand why I can't find the triggers sub-package. Do I miss something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there was already a "definitions" module in my python version.

Below are the steps I followed. First I imported the definitions module. Then I printed the modules loaded. And finally, I realized that the path to the package/module was not consistent to where my project was located.

```
import definitions
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.modules))
```

It outputs:

```
...
source.genetic_algorithm
definitions
```

Then you can get the location of the module by doing:

```
print(sys.modules['definitions'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to do a relative import, which requires a leading period ('.') character. Try

```
from .definitions.triggers import <function>
```

More details at [The Python Import System docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html).

Comment: I think I am doing an absolute import. I am importing the modules as if I was located at the root directory (FCM)

Comment: That won't work in this context; you have to do a relative import.

Comment: This thread answers that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time. See BrenBam's answer.